# Matrix Derivative of Normalized Quadratic Form with inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Fix $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and define the function
$$
\begin{aligned}
f:\operatorname{Mat}_{d\times d} & \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d\\
A & \mapsto \frac1{a^TA^{-1}b} \cdot A^{-1} b,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\cdot$ is scalar multiplication.

---

I want to differentiate $f$ with respect to $A$.  Here's what I have computed so far:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial
a^TAb
}{\partial A} = & a^Tb\\
\frac{\partial A^{-1}b}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}b
\end{aligned}
$$
So.. applying the chain rule a couple times yields
$$
\frac{\partial \frac1{a^TA^{-1}b}}{\partial A} = 
\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A} \left(
\frac{a^Tb}{a^T A^{-1} b}
\right).
$$

At this point I get stuck... what is $\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}$ and what is the scalar-multiplication analogue of the product rule (so I can combine $\frac{\partial \frac1{a^TA^{-1}b}}{\partial A}$ with $\frac{\partial A^{-1}b}{\partial A}$....)

**Update:**
For $A^{-1}$'s derivative I compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
0=&\frac{\partial I}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial (AA^{-1})}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial A}{\partial A}A^{-1} + A\frac{\partial (A^{-1})}{\partial A}\\
\therefore \frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}=&-A^{-1}IA^{-1} = -(A^{-1})^2= -A^{-2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: use the identity $AA^{-1} =I$ and differentiate. Use the product rule on the LHS, on the RHS you will get 0.

Comment: @Mick  Thanks for the tip... I made some update but I'm still stuck on the scalar assembling bit..

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the vector $a$ to $c$, and re-purpose the name to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the matrix
$$a = \operatorname{vec}\left(A\right)$$ 
Define the scalar variable
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= c^TA^{-1}b \\
d\phi &= -c^TA^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1}b \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this scalar.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \phi^{-1}A^{-1}b \\
df &= d\phi^{-1}A^{-1}b\, + \phi^{-1}dA^{-1}b \\
   &= -\phi^{-2}A^{-1}b\,d\phi - \phi^{-1}A^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1}b \\
   &= f\,\phi^{-1}(c^TA^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1}b) - A^{-1}\,dA\,f \\
   &= f\left(c^TA^{-1}\,dA\,f\right) - A^{-1}\,dA\,f \\
   &= \left(fc^T-I\right)\left(A^{-1}\,dA\,f\right) \\
   &= \left(fc^T-I\right)\left(f^T\otimes A^{-1}\right)da \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}
   &= \left(fc^T-I\right)\left(f^T\otimes A^{-1}\right) \\
}$$
The requested gradient (of a vector with respect to a matrix) is actually a third-order **tensor** and cannot be expressed in standard matrix notation.  So this vectorized result is about the best you can do.